# Bootstrap span classes not working as expected

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wrote my first bootstrap program.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span9">Level 1 of Column</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span6">Level 2</div>
            <div class="span3">Level 2</div>
        </div>

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>    
</html>
```

My hope was that the div class 9 will only take up 9 columns instead of entire browser width. My hope was that span6 and span3 will take up 6 and 3 columns and will be in the same row.

But the output looks like

[image]

So the rows do not appear properly (they are being cut) and also the rows and columns are not being respected. (in chrome I can see that level 1 is taking up the entire browser width) so is the 2 span6 and span3 classes. they take up entire browser width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You refer to bootstrap 3.1.1 css file in your header, but you are using bootstrap 2 css classes (e.g. `span3`) within your html code.

Use bootstrap 3 classes instead as described here:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/

So for example use `col-lg-3` instead of `span3`.

Try this:

```
...
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-9">Level 1 of Column</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">Level 2</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">Level 2</div>
</div>
...
```