# span4, span3 bootstrap not aligning

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to make a layout in bootstrap, by aligning two divs beside each other as an author is doing, here's the code am doing:

```
 <div class="row">
             <div class="span3">
                   <div><strong>Date:</strong> 1/1/1900</div>
             </div>
             <div class="span4">
                   <address>
                        <strong>Address:</strong><br/>
                       Our Offices<br/>
                       New York, USA
                   </address>
             </div> 
       </div>
```

The author has results that the contents of span3 and span4 are aligned next to each other, but for me they are appearing under each other, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap span classes not working as expected](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23046404/bootstrap-span-classes-not-working-as-expected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.span*` classes are from Bootstrap v2. Bootstrap v3 is not backward-compatible with Bootstrap v2 and replaced those classes with [the `.col-*-*` classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options).

You are presumably using Bootstrap v3 but looking at Bootstrap v2 examples/tutorials. Don't do that. Consult Bootstrap v3 materials when using Bootstrap v3.

Answer (score 0):

Add the `.col-md-6` class, or any other size (e.g. `.col-sm-6`) to the divs. You don't have any CSS defined for `.span3` or `.span4`.

```
<div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-6">
               <div><strong>Date:</strong> 1/1/1900</div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-6">
               <address>
                    <strong>Address:</strong><br/>
                   Our Offices<br/>
                   New York, USA
               </address>
         </div> 
   </div>
```